# JavaScript, How to somehow crypt output value of a "spinning wheel"

Tags: javascript, encryption

I created some kind of a "spinning wheel". Main difference is that it is not setting "win" value on click start button, but its start spinning for 10sec and you have to click when arrow is pointing exact vield/value you want. Arrow stops spinning instantly on this value. So it is more like you have to aim and shoot on good field.

Another example could be just dot/stripe that is forever moving from left to right wall and you have to stop it(click it) on middle for example if you want to get best value

```
[-|-------]
[------|--]
[--------|]
[------|--]
[-|-------]
```

I have trouble with trying to somehow make it non-cheatable, so user can't send POST request with value he put in DATA. It have to work only when clicking manually.

Only one idea I come up with is that I could crypt data, but it would be easy to just revert this encryption reading javascript code.

Any suggestions/ideas how I could make it non-cheatable?

Maybe using flash animation would be better?

Comment: I think the only way you can make this uncheatable is if you make the decision on the server side. Anything you do on the client side can be reverse engineered.

Comment: Let the user only send you the time he clicked it and calculate in your backend, what he hit. Still, can't be made uncheatable with that, but a bit better. You can't fully make this game uncheatable, because it requires real human interaction, which can always be faked by a robot (or a manual POST request in that case). You would have to make your own client, check if the connection is manipulated, and so on and so on. Why do you think games like CS:GO are still full of cheaters despite the amout of developers? Because Anti-cheat is and never will be perfect.

Comment: I am fully aware of this, I just don't want it to be able to cheat with reading one POST request. Also about timestamp, I was thinking about this but I am not sure if this would be always 100% correct. I think script could slow down for a bit if its laggy for example and it would lose synchronization